# How do I disconnect battery from motherboard in Asus Zenbook?

Tags: asus-laptop, zenbook, disassembly

I'm trying to disconnect the battery from the motherboard, following instructions from another forum to hopefully salvage my laptop that won't turn on at all.

I've been able to do everything except for the life of me I can't figure out how to disconnect the battery from the motherboard where it "clips" in. [image: clip connecting motherboard and battery on Asus Zenbook ux305FA]

I tried using a tiny computer screwdriver head to push those black squares that look like pins at the top and bottom of the clip but they don't budge. What am I doing wrong here? How do I get it to release? (and yes, I haven't worked in the guts of a computer for a very long time)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you remove the tape so see what's beneath it? You might simply be able to pull the connector off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I get it to release?

> Pry up each side of the flat connectors by hand or with a plastic opening tool.
>
> [image]

Source [Asus Zenbook UX32VD Battery Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Asus+Zenbook+UX32VD+Battery+Replacement/52272)

See also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tn7tADDxFkM) at 2:15 minutes in.